# Ventana Modal para crear nuevo registro

Tags: django

Estoy  tratando  de implementar  una ventana  modal  como lo hace  Django con el  signo +,  Ya me aparece la ventana  modal  pero  tengo  un problema  no se como  cargar el  froms.py  pues no tengo la caja de texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo en una parte del menu la opcion de Nuevo Alumno  con una  url y AlumnoForm.py donde utilizo el (forms.ModelForm) y todo funciona  bien..

Cuales  son los  pasos a  seguir para  que esto  funcione.?
tengo  que  crear  algun Ajax  para  cargar el  formulario ?

Alguien que  me  pueda  orientar  como  hacer esto..

Gracias.

Codigo del  template modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                   Alumno Nuevo
                </h4>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method='POST' action="/addalumno/">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Nombre:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.nombreAlumno}} {{form.nombreAlumno.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sexo" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Sexo:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.sexo}} {{form.sexo.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="coloniaal" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Colonia Alumno:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.coloniaal}} {{form.coloniaal.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="callenumal" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Calle Alumno:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.callenumal}} {{form.callenumal.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="localidadal" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Localidad Alumno:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.localidadal}} {{form.localidadal.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" -->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="discapacidad" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Discapacidad:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.discapacidad}} {{form.discapacidad.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="escolaridad" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Escolaridad:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.escolaridad}} {{form.escolaridad.errors}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" -->
          </div>
          <!--<div class="row"> -->
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Cerrar
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Guardar
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente tienes que utilizar una petición Ajax. Te recomiendo utilices [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) para esto.

Adicionalmente deberás de crear una vista que recibirá los datos del formulario. En esta vista recibiras cada uno de los campos y los guardaras en tu modelo. Luego puedes devolver un JSON con informacion de error o exito, para que puedas actualizar tu ventana.

Ejemplo sencillo, puedes mejorarlo:

```
<!-- En tu archivo html -->

<div id="modal">
    <form id="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="alumno_nombre"></input>
        <input type="text" name="alumno_apellido"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

El modal contiene un formulario con un campo llamado `'alumno_nombre'` y `'alumno_apellido'`

```
<script>
    var nombre_alumno = $('input[name="alumno_nombre"]').val();
    var apellido_alumno = $('input[name="alumno_apellido"]').val();

    $.post("/alumno/nuevo_alumno", { nombre: nombre_alumno, apellido: apellido_alumno } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( data.mensaje );
        });
</script>
```

Hacemos el post a la url y mostramos en pantalla el mensaje que nos devolvió Django.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Alumno(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Ejemplo del modelo.

```
# views.py
from app.models import Alumno
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def nuevo_alumno(request):
   nombre_alumno = request.POST.get('nombre', None)
   apellido_alumno = request.POST.get('apellido', None)

   try:
       alumno = Alumno(nombre = nombre_alumno, apellido = apellido_alumno)
       alumno.save()
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"mensaje": "Alumno guardado exitosamente."}), content_type='application/json')
   except:
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"mensaje": "ERROR"}), content_type='application/json')
```

Aquí hacemos el guardado del alumno. Y Django te devolverá un objeto JSON con el mensaje de éxito o error.

Comment: Hola Fermin, gracias  por  tu ayuda,  No me  queda  muy claro, que el modal contiene un formulario. con un campo llamado  tu_dato. En este ejemplo  debo  crear  un forms.py  con  solo un campo que es 'tu_dato' .?

Comment: Hola Tony, fue error mio. ya corregí la respuesta en vez de 'tu_dato' es 'alumno_nombre'. 

Dentro del modal puedes crear tu formulario con los campos donde vas a ingresar la informacion de tu nuevo alumno. 

Esto lo puede hacer utilizando el generador de formularios de Django o bien puedes escribirlo tu manualmente. Yo prefiero manual ya que tengo mas control sobre el código. Luego sustraes el valor de cada campo y lo mandas en el $.post.

Answer (score 0):

En Bootstrap las ventanas modales existen **antes** ocultas desde el momento en que se carga la página. Cuando las activas **no se crean**, solo se muestran.

Dicho esto, en tu ventana modal, preparas al formulario, pensando en que se va a crear el formulario al hacer clic en el signo de más, pero estás creando el formulario con la variable `form`, pero esa variable contiene el formulario de **Nueva atención** y no el de Nuevo alumno.

Para que puedas visualizar el formulario de Nuevo alumno, **tienes que enviarlo** a tu formulario o cargarlo a tu modal desde un archivo externo.

Recuerda que si eliges enviarlo a tu formulario, debes enviarlo con otra variable, por ejemplo `form2`. Con la carga externa, no tendrías problema, consulta la documentación: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options.